# Word for: the act of translating binary into text

Tags: word-request

What do you call the act of translating binary into text?

Is it just called **encoding**, and the process of translating text into binary called **decoding**?

I think *encoding* and *decoding* are too general, so is there a word specific for encoding from binary into text?

Comment: If those terms are applicable (I'm not sure they are), it would be the *opposite* of what you've said. People read text, not binary. You *encode* something into something unreadable, and you *decode* it back into something that is readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no specific word. So use the phrase "Convert text to binary"

Think about what you actually mean.

"00100001 00100010" and "ab" are both text. The first is the "binary dump" of the second.  But you would only normally want to make a binary dump if you are converting octets that can't be represented as text. And you would prefer to make a "hexdump" instead.